# How to insert a real tab with Vim SuperTab plugin if completion fails

Tags: vim, text-editors, vim-plugins

I really like vim [SuperTab](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab) plugin.

But there is a little problem I have.

When there is no keyword to complete the plugin doesn't insert a real tab but instead it tries to complete the word with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> showing an error.

I know that I can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to insert a real tab but I'd like an auto fallback function.

I also know I can write a custom function to accomplish this task but I don't have the vim scripting competence to do this.

Is there any configuration of vim or SuperTab that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

While in insert mode type `<C-V> Tab`.

`<C-V>` is used as a prefix to insert special characters.

see `:help ins-special-keys` for more information.