# How can i insert a tab after choosing a proposed completion in vim

Tags: vim, tabs, autocomplete

I thought I knew the answer to this.

I used to do `<C-V> tab` as suggested in ["How to insert a real tab with Vim SuperTab plugin if completion fails"](https://superuser.com/questions/493223/how-to-insert-a-real-tab-with-vim-supertab-plugin-if-completion-fails) and many others.

If i `set list` though, I can see that I get an actual tab instead of my four spaces (with expandtab set) and that really messes up my code.

Is there a way to:

1. write
2. chooses some suggested autocompletion
3. insert tab (as defined with expandtab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- SuperTab has a fallback; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> by default. See `:help g:SuperTabMappingTabLiteral`. I think pressing this should suffice. (You can also change the config to use another key, or `:inoremap <F1> <Tab>` yourself).
- You can conclude the completion with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> (cp. `:help complete_CTRL-Y`); this closes the popup menu and therefore the special handling of `<Tab>`.
- If all that doesn't help, try concluding the completion by pressing <kbd>Space</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd>. The former avoids that SuperTab is triggered again, and the latter will expand the whitespace to the next tabstop value, and format it according to your indent settings.

Comment: Using Space and then Tab was just what I wanted to avoid since it could mean that your first space brings you to a tab-stop and the following tab takes you one more forward. CRTL-Y or CTRL_SPACE works fine though, thanks.